# Best opensource maps solution for java dynamic application similar to bing maps

Tags: google-maps, maps, bing-maps

I would like to use maps in my web application to plot various points. 
Which one should i use google maps or bing or some other?
Using bing maps is free??
I expect a free solution.
Is there any that i can use?
Thanks.

Comment: Bing Maps does have some free usage options for public facing applications that generate under a certain amount of transactions. If you are creating a mobile or Win8 app then you can generate 50,000 transactions a day for free. If you are creating a web app then you can get 125,000 transactions a year for free.

Answer (score 0):

The only one that I know of that's actually Open Source as specified is Open Street Map: http://www.openstreetmap.org/. The map tiles are generated in a crowd sourced manner, and the entire dataset is free to download/play with.

You'll need a seperate data interaction layer (unlike Google Maps or Bing), the best I know of is OpenLayers: http://openlayers.org/ again, open source and free to use/fiddle with as you will.